# IIS - set default page via command line

Tags: iis, iis-6

I would like to setup IIS via a batch file. How do I set/add default pages to a website?

[image: The files in the list of the Documents tab]

Answer (score 1):

You can use appcmd.exe:

`appcmd set config /section:defaultDocument /enabled:true|false`

Check appcmd help at MSDN (or [here](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/114/getting-started-with-appcmdexe)) for more information.

Comment: I thought appcmd.exe was for IIS7? Does it work on 6 too?

Comment: @Kenny Is right, Appcmd doesn't come with IIS6 (it was introduces with IIS7).  Not sure if you can use the II7 version on IIS6 or not.